# change entity framework core code first migration name format

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

ef core using system calendar format for generating migration names.

example of standard migration name for the Gregorian calendar on windows:

```
20190206144020_MIGRATION-NAME
```

But if the date format of Windows is something other than the Gregorian, like Persian calendar the ef core migration name generates something like :

```
13971114210223_MIGRATION-NAME
```

in a team project, we cannot use both formats because it's changing the order of migrations.

is there any way to fix that issue without changing windows calendar format or manually rename the migration?

*version: EF core 2.2*

Comment: I didn't find a solution but seems like this issue fixed in the next major version (3.0) 

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/15045

Comment: I think you need to do a second migration and pass the new name through the folder that is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply a bug in the [MigrationsIdGenerator](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/v2.2.4/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Internal/MigrationsIdGenerator.cs) class for the latest at this time EF Core 2.2.4 - in the [last line](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/v2.2.4/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Internal/MigrationsIdGenerator.cs#L57) of `GenerateId` method:

```
return timestamp.ToString(Format) + "_" + name;
```

they simply forgot to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to `DateTime.Format` method.

It's [already fixed in the current code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Internal/MigrationsIdGenerator.cs#L73) (I believe for EF Core 3.0), so you either wait for it, or copy/paste the current code to your project (rename the class to let say `FixedMigrationsIdGenerator`) and then inside your `DbContext` derived class, override `OnConfiguring` and add the following (with the necessary `using`s):

```
optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsIdGenerator, FixedMigrationsIdGenerator>();
```

Answer (score 4):

I've extended the accepted answer and created a class derived from the `MigrationsIdGenerator` class overriding only the `GenerateId` method:

```cs
public class FixedMigrationsIdGenerator : MigrationsIdGenerator
{
    private const string Format = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";

    private DateTime _lastTimestamp = DateTime.MinValue;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public override string GenerateId(string name)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var timestamp = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (timestamp <= _lastTimestamp)
            {
                timestamp = _lastTimestamp.AddSeconds(1);
            }

            _lastTimestamp = timestamp;
        }

        return timestamp.ToString(Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "_" + name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the command prompt file or batch file (.cmd) to create a name automatically (including date and time). Doing so I just need to double-click the .cmd file and the migration with my own automatic file name will be performed.
here is my .cmd file content (for example add_migrations_Identity.cmd):

```
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c_%%a_%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME: =0%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
dotnet ef --startup-project MyProject migrations add Identity_V%mydate%_%mytime% -o Migrations/Identity -c IdentityContext
pause
```

and here my update .cmd file (as an example update_db_Identity.cmd):

```
dotnet ef --startup-project MyProject database update -c IdentityContext
pause
```